# How to get spinner's selected item's view

Tags: java, android, xml, android-spinner, android-adapter

I'm trying to get a reference to the view of the selected item of my spinner (the layout). I'm using a `SimpleCursorAdapter` with a custom layout. Here is some of the code for my adapter:

```
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
            R.layout.task_row, null,
            new String[] { DbHandler.TASK_TITLE, DbHandler.TASK_NOTE},
            new int[] { R.id.title, R.id.note}, 0);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here is **task_row.xml**:

```
<RelativeLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/avatar"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/avatar" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/avatar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/note"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/avatar"
    android:layout_below="@id/title"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The reason I'm trying to get a reference to the `RelativeLayout` is so that I can access the `text` attribute of a `TextView` child for example. I'm aware that there is a method called `getItemSelected()` that I can use on my `Spinner`, but this method returns an object and I don't know what it is.

Comment: hello i think you have a custom adapter and from the adapter you want to get spinner value

Comment: Hi. I'm using a SimpleCursorAdapter (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html). Here the "value" of the spinner doesn't make sense since what is displayed is my custom layout with an ImageView and two TextViews. What i want is the text attribute of one of the TextView childs, for the selected item. If it is possible to get it from the adapter, then sure.

Comment: have you tried to get value from the view?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do. But I need a reference to it.

Comment: ok i have seen it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using,

```
  spinner.getSelectedItem()
```

which return null, so use this :

```
  ((TextView)(spinner.getSelectedView().findViewById(R.id.title))).getText()
```

I think it work for you.

In this case, you will be having whole selected view also, **which is you requirement i think** by:

```
  spinner.getSelectedView()
```

Comment: Yes that's what i was looking for. We posted our answers almost simultaneously. I'm accepting yours. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code that would help to show the selected value at the top of spinner index

```
                    spinnner.setSelection(arraylist.indexOf(selectedString));
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your answer. How does this give me a reference to the layout? Plus, what is your arraylist variable?

Comment: here array list referenced to where you store the whole list data .

Comment: selectedString shows which string or data you want to selected at first position of spinner

Comment: I'm not using an array but a SQLite database with a SimpleCursorAdapter as I said in my question. But regardless, how does this give me a reference to the layout?

Comment: I'm sorry but this is not what I asked for :/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a reference to a text view in your layout, I'm assuming so that you can set a string resource based on the selected spinner item the user selects, Put this code in your onCreate method that has the spinner:

```
// create a reference to the spinner, replace mySpinnerId with actual spinner id
final Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.mySpinnerId);
// create a reference to the text view, replace myTextViewId with actual text view id
final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextViewId);

    mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parameter, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            // get the string value of the spinner item that is selected
            String selectedSpinnerItem = String.valueOf(mySpinner.getSelectedItem());

            // set the description in the Text View if it matches some
            // string resource in your array, replace option1 with actual
            // string resource to obtain
            if (selectedSpinnerItem.equals(getString(R.string.option1)))
            {
                // replace myStringResource with actual string resource name
                textView.setText(R.string.myStringResource);
            }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
        {
        }
    });
}
```

The caveat for this to work this is that, in your strings.xml file, define your string-array for your spinner like so:

```
<string name="option1">An option:</string>
<string name="option2">Another option:</string>
<string-array name="spinner_options">
    <item>@string/option1</item>
    <item>@string/option2</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: Where is this code supposed to go? It cannot go into the activity whose layout contains the spinner because the TextView I'm trying to access doesn't belong to the same layout as the spinner.

Comment: @JalilCompaoré Oh, I see what you are saying now. But I don't think it should matter, since you have a reference to the text view by id, did you try it?

Comment: @JalilCompaoré So, I think this code still applies, and you want to put it in the activity onCreate method that has the spinner

Comment: It can't apply. When my code run, I have multiple items in my spinner, meaning I have multiple TextViews with the same id. Which one would be returned by findViewById(R.id.myTextViewId)?

Comment: @JalilCompaoré You can't use all the code exactly as is, You can use most of it, but you have to replace things like myTextViewId with that actual id of the text view you want. and the R.string.option1 with the actual string reference you want to refer to, and myStringResource, with the actual string resource you want. So if you wanted to refer to @+id/note text view, then say TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.note); Same with the Spinner reference.

Comment: I know. Do you agree that in order for findViewById() to find something, that something has to be a child of what we're calling findViewById() on? Here, the TextView is not a child of the activity. It is part of my custom layout task_row.xml that defines how a single item should be displayed inside my spinner. It has nothing to do with the activity's layout.

Comment: @JalilCompaoré I know that my app has three activities with three different layouts, and I can reference their views from any of the activities by using findViewById()

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem. The `Spinner` class extends `AdapterView<SpinnerAdapter>` which has a method called `getSelectedView()` that does exactly what its name suggests.